# How can I select from object array in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an object array in my angular (typescript) Project.

```
let a = [{min:0, max:10},{min:10, max:810},{min:-10, max:110}];
```

So I want to get minimum of min, and maximum of the max items. I need two variables like following:

```
let min = // minimum of all items min property = -10;
let max = // maximum of all items max property = 810;
```

can I do this using lambda or other ways practically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` to get all min/max values. Use `Math.min` and `Math.max` to get the values.

```js
let a = [{min:0, max:10},{min:10, max:810},{min:-10, max:110}];

let min = Math.min(...a.map(o => o.min));
let max = Math.max(...a.map(o => o.max));

console.log(min);
console.log(max);
```

Another option is using `reduce`. This option only needs to loop the array once.

```js
let a = [{min:0, max:10},{min:10, max:810},{min:-10, max:110}];

let min = a.reduce((c, v) => v.min < c ? v.min : c, 0);
let max = a.reduce((c, v) => v.max > c ? v.max : c, 0);

console.log(min);
console.log(max);
```

Comment: what means "..." in front of a.map?

Comment: That is spread syntax. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 1):

```
let min = Math.min(...a.map((item)=>{return item.min}))
let max = Math.max(...a.map((item)=>{return item.max}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 let a = [{min:0, max:10},{min:10, max:810},{min:-10, max:110}];

    let min = Math.min(...a.map(value => value.min));
    let max = Math.max(...a.map(value => value.max));
```

Comment: `_`is a library that is not part of native javaScript. If using underscore this would be a good answer. However, since OP is not asking about underscore/lodash I think this answer is not correct.